# Is it ok to create a custom test tool console app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops

Without using any test framework, I created some integration and unit tests in a console application in Visual Studio. I used e.g. refelection to start methods with then name like Testxxx...

The exceptions are saved and displayed, really easy and simple.

I would like to start it in azure dev-ops as a command line post-build task.
I can e.g. also send e-mails with the results (on failure).

Because it's so elementary and versatile I wonder whether others also did this?
I wonder though, how would I then output the results in the build pipeline?

Comment: Hi Gerard, sounds like a broad question. 

Which language are you using?

If server side, have you tried using on the popular testing frameworks instead (NUnit, xUnit, MSTest)? This gives you reporting, IDE integration etc for free and despite the names you can also use them for integration testing.

Comment: It also sounds like you implemented your own testing framework. While there is learning value in that from an academic point of view, can you explain what keeps you from using one of the free existing alternatives (NUnit, xUnit, MSTest etc)?

Comment: I tried but noticed that exc. messages are not reported in the output - then I was disappointed. I would like an e-mail with the message and also the message in the pipeline output. These tools don't seem to do that.

Comment: Can you post the code you used? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example